# Why do my rigid body objects have gaps in between them?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I have tried to make a rigid body simulation to make apples look more realistic but when I start the simulation, apples are not touching each other they have a lot of space between them and when I tried to apply rigid body simulation it didn't applied.

[image: Rigid body simulation isn't working]

Comment: In the object's properties collision section, there is a subsection called sensitivity. In there is the 'Margin' parameter, this might be too big. Try setting it to different values to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: here is the problem: I dont have collision section in my object properties part

Comment: I have also tried to change margin in sensivity from rigid body physic but still same nothing is changing

Comment: Sorry I meant collision section in the physics :)

Comment: Wait I am not using collision physic in my apple I am using rigid body. Should I?

Comment: Sorry I meant physics>Rigid Body >Collision. I'm old and senile. I had a problem in a tutorial that was solved by changing the 'Margin' parameter. By the way, possibly its coincidence, but the gap between the surface of the apples looks like 2x the length of the stalk protrusion

Comment: If the last comment doesn't work try increasing the solves per second.

Comment: I`m also facing same issue, with sensitivity went down all the way to 0.005M.
 
I feel blender doc about physics isnt complete and could talk more about the dependencies it have with the scene.
the mesh collision mode causes some weird behaviors